# Getting Client IP over HTTPS

Tags: c#

**Background**

We use HTTPS site-wide on IIS servers. We are evaluating MaxMind's geoIP lookup service to help determine if registering clients are in the USA, which is where we will be offering our regional services.

**Question C# Code**

In the past, I have used code similar to the following to detect client IP addresses over HTTP. I know IP addresses can be easily spoofed over HTTP through proxy servers.

---

**Update**

I wanted to point out a misconception that I had regarding HTTPS/IP Spoofing. This [Link](https://docs.alertlogic.com/userGuides/web-security-manager-premier-preserve-IP-address.htm) which shows how to preserve the client IP address, mentions that this is only valid for trusted proxies, which I really cannot control from my server.

This is a point that I obviously missed. If a client request is routed through a proxy, is would appear that a client can hide their IP address even over SSL.

User Evk provided an [example](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147166/how-can-you-fake-geolocation-in-firefox/147176#147176) where Firefox can be used to spoof a longitude/latitude check in the browser. I checked this out on the HTML5 demos website and through our SPA running SSL. In both cases, Firefox yielded a bogus location in NY.

**Back to the Original Question**

Poke helped correct some additional misconceptions I had about the first section of C# code regarding reverse proxies.

Thanks much to all for your input. Really appreciate it.

---

```
    var clientpAddr = string.Empty;
    // Is this first condition really necessary with HTTPS?
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null) {
        // Field format is: client1, proxy1, proxy2, ...
        clientpAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
    } else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress)) {
        clientpAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientpAddr))
        LogFileWriter.WriteLine(clientpAddr);
```

In all our testing of mobile and desktop devices using HTTPS, we have only observed one returned IP address from the above code.

1. Is the first part of the code unnecessary when using HTTPS?
2. Is there a more full proof/superior way of dealing with the HTTPS scenario?

I have found a lot of information on HTTP, but next to zero on HTTPS.

Thanks...

Comment: The issue with HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is that its trivial to add any address you like in the X-Forwarded-For request header. HTTPS does not mitigate this.

Comment: Why would using HTTP or HTTPS change whether it's possible for IP addresses to be "spoofed" through proxy servers?

Comment: Alex K Thanks for the feedback. From what I have read, the client IP address cannot be spoofed over HTTPS. 1) If not correct, do you have a definitive source?. 2) Does that mean that HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress will always return client IP address?

Comment: "From what I have read, this should not be the case using HTTPS." - would You mind to share some sources on this behalf? I'm kind of interested in this topic. Thanks

Comment: john, when a client negotiates a secure connection using, say DigiCert certs, how is the client IP spoofed? I am all ears. Thanks...

Comment: It is not in any way required that proxy\vpn will send X Forwarded For (or any other similar) header. If I want to use your api from outside of US - I will use vpn\proxy located in US and all you will see is IP of that vpn\proxy - it will not send my real ip address in any header. It doesn't matter if I use https or not in this case.

Comment: Crowcoder, Thanks, I am aware of the VPN exception.

Comment: Evk, Thanks. Can you point to a source that explains this in more detail. I am here to learn. I do understand the VPN scenario. Is this the only case? Otherwise, I do not understand how a point-to-point SSL connection can be spoofed through proxies, which is easy to do for HTTP.

Comment: But proxy is not much different from VPN in this case. I want to establish SSL connection to you though proxy. I will connect to proxy and it will connect to you and just forward all SSL traffic back and forth, it doesn't even need to decrypt it.

Comment: Evk, So, what you are saying is that you or IT personnel would configure proxies to download our javascript/html single page app when you enter our URL into a browser using HTTPS. The proxy or somewhere in the chain removes all IP addresses or substitutes bogus ones. Correct? Without hacking into our code, it seems that a geolocation request would yield your real location. Is this true or false? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Proxy does not remove or substitute any bogus ip addresses. When I enter url of your application in browser - all traffic will go to a proxy (regular proxy, no hacks). Proxy will forward all traffic as is to your web server and will forward responses back to me as is (no decryption\encryption). Because your web server is talking only with proxy - you will not be able to figure my real ip address in any way. So you only know IP address of a proxy (though you have no idea that it's a proxy), for which you will issue a geolocation request.

Comment: Evk, You have been very helpful. One more question. If you click on a Verify Location button and allow the location verification request in your browser, why would the longitude/latitude coordinates be for the proxy and not your physical location?

Comment: I assumed you mean geolocation based on ip address. However, its easy to fake browser geolocation too. You are in a full control of a browser so you can do anything you like. For an example see here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/147176 how you can set whatever location you like in firefox in 30 seconds. But without such modifications it might indeed reveal your location even when behind proxy\vpn, because it uses different technique (like collecting identifiers of local wifi networks, or getting your ip address directly, or maybe even using GPS directly if on device with GPS).

Comment: Tatranskymedved, I didn't keep all the resources I looked at, but this link: https://docs.alertlogic.com/userGuides/web-security-manager-premier-preserve-IP-address.htm  is one that seems to imply that the client IP address can be preserved using X-Forwarded-For option, but evidently I am mistaken, as others have been pointing out.

Comment: That document and the `X-Forwarded` headers are in regards to a *reverse proxy*. That is software that runs on your servers and will be the front facing web server clients will connect to. This has nothing to do with client-side proxies or VPNs. – Certain proxies and VPNs may or may not leave doors open that would allow you to detect their usage but bottom line is: It’s impossible to guarantee that the IP address you receive is the *actual* client’s IP address. Give me a server in the US, and I can easily tunnel all my connections through it without you being able to detect it.

Comment: As for `X-Fowarded-For` (since that appears to be the main thing you are asking about, although you are confusing it for something it is not), check [Wikipedia for an explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For).

Comment: Your input is very helpful. I will adjust my edit above and head off to do a lot more research/studying. Thanks for taking the time to help edify me.

Comment: Long story short - it is too hard and in general I'd say even impossible to restrict access to your service to users from specific region. Even huge services with billions of cash (like netflix) cannot do this. They blacklist certain ip ranges which they know belong to big vpn providers, but you still can get in with smaller/custom ones.

Comment: "geoIP lookup over HTTPS is quite accurate at the country level"

This statement is not true. If a user is behind an VPN, he can still connect using HTTPS and you have no idea where they where from.